# How to split time intervals into disjoint time intervals and count number of rows in them?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data with recordings of people visiting some place. There are time intervals of visits. I want to count how many people are there at what time.

For example with toy data :

```sql
create table data ( id int, start_time datetime, end_time datetime);
insert into data values (1, '2019-11-06 09:32:00', '2019-11-06 09:41:00');
insert into data values (2, '2019-11-06 09:35:00', '2019-11-06 09:43:00');
```

I expect to get

```
    start_time              end_time           count 
2019-11-06 09:32:00   2019-11-06 09:35:00        1
2019-11-06 09:35:00   2019-11-06 09:41:00        2
2019-11-06 09:41:00   2019-11-06 09:43:00        1
```

How can I implement this efficiently in SQL Server?

Comment: How do you decide on these time intervals? I can't seem to figure the logic. 3 minutes, 6 minutes and 2 minutes?

Comment: Looks like each distinct value of `start_time` and `end_time`, @sagi .

Comment: @sagi, they overlap. So from 09:32 to 09:35 there is only the first visitor, then the second comes and there are two visitors until 09:41, then the first leaves and remains only the second until 09:43. So I want to split the union of these time intervals into set of disjoint time intervals and calculate the number of people for each such interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you need to do is unpivot your times, use `LEAD`, to get the next time, and then re-`JOIN` to your table with the new "buckets". For the sample data we have, this works:

```sql
WITH Times AS(
    SELECT V.[Time] AS Start_Time,
           LEAD(V.Time) OVER (ORDER BY V.Time) AS End_Time
    FROM dbo.data d
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(d.start_time),(d.end_time))V([Time]))
SELECT T.Start_Time,
       T.End_Time,
       COUNT(d.id) AS [Count]
FROM Times T
     LEFT JOIN dbo.data d ON d.start_time < T.End_Time
                         AND d.end_time > T.Start_Time
WHERE T.End_Time IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY T.Start_Time,
         T.End_Time;
```

Comment: Thanks, that really works! However, can you please elaborate a little what is going on? For example how can I modify it to add grouping by id of the place.

Comment: You would likely need to include the place id in the definition of the `Times` CTE, and then include it in the `JOIN`'s `ON` clause, @Nourless . Have a go at solving that yourself and if you can't solve the problem, then ask a **new question**; showing your attempts to solve the new problem.